# Upload audio and video files on to server

Tags: android, audio, video, upload

I want to upload audio video and image files on to server using php and android.
I have gone through many codes and examples but didn't find any proper example for uploading audio and video.
I have successfully done with the image upload part,so kindly help me with the uploading of video and audio part.I want to set upload size to max 10MB audio and video

Here is the code which I have tried for audio upload but didn't got it

```
    package com.sunil.upload;


import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
    String selectedPath = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        openGalleryAudio();
    }

    public void openGalleryAudio(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), SELECT_AUDIO);
   }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == SELECT_AUDIO)
            {
                System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + selectedPath);
                doFileUpload();
            }

        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload(){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "rn";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://192.168.1.102/upload_audio.php";
        try
        {
         //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);
         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
         dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="";filename="" + selectedPath + """ + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         // create a buffer of maximum size
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         while (bytesRead > 0)
         {
          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }
         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
         // close streams
         Log.e("Debug","File is written");
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
              inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
              String str;

              while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
              }
              inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
      }
}
```

I did not got this code

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="";filename="" + selectedPath + """ + lineEnd);
```

How should I modify this statement

PHP file

```
    $target_path = "uploads/";



$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);



if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).

    " has been uploaded";

} else{

    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";

}
```

Thank you

here is logcat

```
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/[Songs.PK] 01 - 2 States - Offo.mp3 }} to activity {com.sunil.upload/com.sunil.upload.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at com.sunil.upload.MainActivity.getPath(MainActivity.java:63)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at com.sunil.upload.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:52)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
03-20 09:22:28.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     ... 11 more
03-20 09:23:13.545: E/Trace(3599): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/[Songs.PK] 01 - 2 States - Offo.mp3 }} to activity {com.sunil.upload/com.sunil.upload.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at com.sunil.upload.MainActivity.getPath(MainActivity.java:63)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at com.sunil.upload.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:52)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
03-20 09:23:19.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3599):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: try below solution and let me what happens?

Comment: check the logcat I have added here @InnocentKiller

Comment: You get this error after replacing this line?

Comment: @InnocentKiller yes after replacing the lines I got this error

Comment: Do you have folder called `uploads` in your server's directory. If not then create it manually.

Comment: yes folder is there but no data is being sent to folder

Comment: What is line number 63 in MainActivity.java

Comment: return cursor.getString(column_index);

Comment: Okay, so you have error exactly over there. I think cursor is not returning file which you want, it's null that's why you are getting nullpointerexception.

Comment: I don't think so as its just returning the name 
what do you think

Comment: also I have used same code for image upload which is  working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50123/discussion-between-sanket-naik-and-innocentkiller)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="";filename="" + selectedPath + """ + lineEnd);
```

with

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""+ selectedPath+ "\"" + lineEnd);
```

Because in your **php** file you have pass `uploadedfile`

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

So you have to pass **uploadedfile** as a name's argument.

Hope this will help you.